# How to install Nvidia -375.39 drivers in Ubuntu 14.04..Error displayed as "X server currently running"

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, cuda

HP laptop
Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit) 
Geforce 830M 
Nvidia Driver -375.39(Latest Checked in Nvidia Site)

My requirements:

1. I have to install Nvidia Latest drivers suppoeted for my system(375.39)
2. After that I have to install cuda 8.0 (Latest)
3. Then, I have to install GPU version Tensorflow

I tried installing Nvidia-375.39 by downloading running it as root.
I got the error as "X server is currently running..Stop it and so on..."
I have completely zero knowledge on X server..."Using: nvidia-installer ncurses user interface
-> Detected 4 CPUs online; setting concurrency level to 4.
-> The file '/tmp/.X0-lock' exists and appears to contain the process ID '16666' of a runnning X server.
ERROR: You appear to be running an X server; please exit X before installing."
Can some one help me on this

Comment: Did you check the Ubuntu driver PPA? https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Answer (score 3):

You need to stop lightdm to install Nvidia drivers.

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

But this will stop the whole desktop. So do the following steps.

1. Press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to go to non-GUI mode. Enter your username and password.
2. Stop lightdm with the above command.
3. Now you can install Nvidia drivers and install CUDA.
4. Once you finished installing it. Restart your computer

   ```
   shutdown now
   ```
5. Now turn on your computer like you normally do.

You will be back with GUI.

Comment: I did that earlier , but while installing the Driver in that mode , i found the error "You are currently running X server ............".
 I tried both in Normal Terminal and in that mode (Ctrl+Alt+F1).
I am getting same error message 

"Using: nvidia-installer ncurses user interface
-> Detected 4 CPUs online; setting concurrency level to 4.
-> The file '/tmp/.X0-lock' exists and appears to contain the process ID '16666' of a runnning X server.
ERROR: You appear to be running an X server; please exit X before installing.

Comment: Thank you for your insights @Shreyash S Sarnayak
Can you help me more with that error log file

Comment: Did you do step 2? Stop lightdm using `sudo service lightdm stop`?

Comment: Yes i did that command . And from Additional Driver tool , i defaulteed the drivers to Nvidia 375.39.....But still i am getting the same error of "X server"

Comment: Ohh.. If the Nvidia 375.39 is selected, then you don't need to install it again. You can skip it. And when you are installing CUDA it will ask to install the Nvidia driver (361.., probably) even then don't install it again (This driver is old and too buggy for ubuntu).

Comment: ok..So , after applying changes in Additional Driver tool  to Nvidia-375.39...Will it be showing the same Nvidia-375.39 driver or defaulted to earlier drivers if i reboot the system

Comment: Yes. It is persistent (it will be the same).  This is my screenshot -
https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8i36.png

Comment: Ok..I got it now.My initial was X Server one....Now i vl try again again and will post the comments later....!
Thank you a lot for your time

Comment: I got defaulted  Nvidia-375.39  from Additonal Tools ....

Comment: Ok.. so CUDA is working??

Comment: If this answer helped please click the tick mark and accept the answer.